# What is the point of having the Stream.Builder.accept(T t) method added in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream

What is the purpose for the `void accept(T t)` method? It appears to be the same as the `Stream.Builder<T> add(T t)` method with the exception of returning void and therefore not being chain-able. Is it somehow more efficient to not return the the Builder object (seems minor)? Is there some use case where you wouldn't want the Builder returned?

I don't see any explanation for the decision in the JDK documentation and didn't find this question on stackoverflow. Apologies if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that this interface extends the `Consumer<T>` interface. So you must have the `void accept(T t)` method. But from a "builder" perspective you want to use the class via a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). Since you have one aspect enforcing the return type `void` (the `Consumer<T>` interface) and the other aspect enforcing the return value `this` (the fluent interface style), it is impossible to have both with the same method. So you have to split it up into two methods.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't noticed the `Consumer` extension. That said, I still don't follow why `Consumer` wasn't designed to be fluent. It was introduced in the same version of java, so it isn't as if they were boxed in by a legacy interface. Is the `void` return simply an oversight (I can accept that), or was it a deliberate design decision?

Comment: @candlebar If Consumer.accept required returning the Consumer itself, it would be pretty difficult to use as a lambda expression.

Comment: @VGR This question came to me as I was trying to learn about lambda expressions. What you say might be true, but aren't a lot of things with lambda assumed based on the context, and couldn't this return type be assumed as well? @Progman If I understand what you are saying, the `Stream.Builder.add(...)` method contradicts you since `Stream.Builder` is an interface and `add(...)` returns a `Stream.Builder`.

Comment: Anything can be designed into a language, but I think it would be confusing enough that it would hinder more than help.  But that’s just my opinion;  I don’t know if it was ever a consideration by the designers.

Comment: @candlebar You are right.

Comment: @candlebar you can pass `builder::add` to a method expecting a `Consumer`, no problem, but being able to pass `builder` directly to, e.g. `Spliterator.tryAdvance` or `forEach`/`forEachRemaining` of collections and streams resp. iterators and spliterators is very convenient.